# using string to display text on serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno

After using int to display text in serial monitor, now i am trying to use string but there is something wrong.
The expected reslut is "Led1 is on" in serial monitor but what i get is "285". 
This is the code involving strings.

```
String(ledPin1="Led1 is on");
Serial.println(ledPin1);
```

while this is the full code

```
int numledPin1Blinks=5;
int ledPin1Blinks=2;
int i;
int j;
int waiTtimeoff2=1000;
int waitTimeOn2=1000;
int ledPin2=10;
int ledPin1=13;
int waiTtimeOn1=1000;
int waiTtimeOff1=1000;
void setup() 
{pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
String(ledPin1="Led1 is on");

}

void loop()
{Serial.println(ledPin1);
for (i=1;i<=3;i=i+1){
Serial.print("   You are on blink 
no#:  ");
Serial.println(i);
digitalWrite(ledPin1,HIGH);
delay(waiTtimeOn1);
digitalWrite(ledPin1,LOW);
delay(waiTtimeOff1);}
Serial.println(" ");

Serial.println("Led 2 is on!");
for (j=1;j<=4;j=j+1){
Serial.print(" You are on blink no 
#:");
Serial.println(j);
digitalWrite (ledPin2,HIGH);
delay(waitTimeOn2);
digitalWrite (ledPin2,LOW);
delay(waiTtimeoff2);}
Serial.println(" ");

}
```

Comment: What do you *think* that code is supposed to do?

Comment: Display ' led 1 is blinking ' in serial monitor.

Comment: Why would it do that? `ledPin1` is just a number and can never be anything else. It's an `int`. All you are doing is assigning the address of a static string to it, turning that number also into a String, and then throwing that string away.

Comment: As an aside: don't try and learn how to use String in the first place. It will lead you down a dark and dismal path that will end in unstable code and tears before bedtime. Don't taint your knowledge with them.  Start straight off with C strings (NULL-terminated character arrays).

Comment: I am learning aurdino from a website ( toptechboy) . The instructor did the same thing as he introduced the concept of string but I'm unable to perform it

Comment: I just perused that site (lesson 5 is it?) There's nothing like that there. The closest is: `String redMessage="The Red LED is Blinking";` which is nothing like you have.

Comment: Yes I think it's lesson 5. I am not copying his code as I want to learn to code that's why my code seems to be different but it has the same structure as on the website

Comment: Please stop answering and use comments instead.

Comment: Maybe you should start with his code and modify it instead of trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: Sorry for not using comments.

Comment: For this case(string) ,  I even copied his code but the problem still persists.

Comment: note: your code is very poorly formatted ... that makes it difficult to read and to spot errors .... proper code formatting should be one of the first things that you learn .... it will help you a lot in the future .... note: your code has errors that prevent it from compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You are assigning the address of a static string literal to an integer, then using the results of that assignment (the address of the string literal, as it "falls through" to the left) to create a new String object. That `String` object is then being thrown away.

You need to create a *new* `String` variable (not re-use one that you actively use for another part of your program) and assign a string literal to it:

```
String led1Message = "LED 1 is on";
```

Then you can print *that* variable instead:

```
Serial.println(led1Message);
```

**HOWEVER** `String` objects are very very fragile on the Arduino and should be avoided. Forget trying to learn to use them, since you will only have to un-learn them at a later date.  Skip them and start straight away with C-strings (NULL-terminated `char` arrays).  Also learn about [`PROGMEM`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/utilities/progmem/).

For instance, the above could be written as:

```
const char led1Message[] PROGMEM = "LED 1 is on";
```

And then use a casting to get `println` to grab it from flash:

```
Serial.println((__FlashStringHelper*)led1Message);
```

This uses pretty much zero RAM, which on an Arduino is very important. Even more important it doesn't cause heap [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)) which can cause your program to crash randomly.

Comment: Thank you very much,  I had no idea about demerits of using strings. I'll just try using const char instead.

Comment: Can `print`/`println` really differentiate between in memory const char and flash one? The `F` macro was using reinterpret cast into FlashStringHelper pointer so function overloading can be used.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure: I never actively *use* Arduino... ;)  You may want to cast it to `(__FlashStringHelper*)`.